# Close Jquery Dialog and set set session c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to close the jquery dialog box and set a session at the same time.  Using asp.net and c#.

Whats the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: jquery dialogs are purely a client-side (browser) element.  Session values are stored exclusively on the server-side, so you'll need to reach to the server (postback or ajax call) to affect the session.  Are you looking for the user to click a single button which closes the dialog and automatically postsback/ajax's-back to the sever?  A code snippet might help us better understand your question.

Comment: as @mikemanne says, we need more info - but if you just want to "set some session value" based on something in the dialog box, and dont care about anything else, then just make an AJAX call to a web service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but you could just close the dialog and make your `$.ajax` call right after that, like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("close");
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "SessionService.svc/RenewSession",
  success: function(data) { alert("success!"); },
  error: function(m, t, x) { alert("error :: " + m + " - " + t); }
});
```

If you want the renew session logic to automatically fire when the dialog is closed, you could attach a function to the close event when you initialize the dialog.  This way, you won't have to make the `$.ajax` call when you close the dialog (like in the code above).  Here's how you'd do this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  //some options
  close: RenewSession
});

function RenewSession() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "SessionService.svc/RenewSession",
    success: function(data) { alert("success!"); },
    error: function(m, t, x) { alert("error :: " + m + " - " + t); }
  });
}
```

Let me know if this is what you're trying to do.  If not, can you provide some more details in your question and I'll update my answer accordingly.  Hope this helps!